# Deploying a model from HuggingFace to Amazon SageMaker: TheBloke/Luna-AI-Llama2-Uncensored-GGML

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, amazon-sagemaker, huggingface, large-language-model

I'm trying to deploy the following huggingface model to Amazon SageMaker:

https://huggingface.co/TheBloke/Luna-AI-Llama2-Uncensored-GGML

I created a domain, launched the studio, and opened a new notebook:

Image: Data Science 3.0

Kernel: Python 3

I tried running the following code:

```
import json

import sagemaker

import boto3

from sagemaker.huggingface import HuggingFaceModel, get_huggingface_llm_image_uri

try:

role = sagemaker.get_execution_role()

except ValueError:

iam = boto3.client('iam')

role = iam.get_role(RoleName='sagemaker_execution_role')['Role']['Arn']

# Hub Model configuration. https://huggingface.co/models

hub = {

'HF_MODEL_ID':'TheBloke/Luna-AI-Llama2-Uncensored-GGML',

'SM_NUM_GPUS': json.dumps(1)

}

# create Hugging Face Model Class

huggingface_model = HuggingFaceModel(

image_uri=get_huggingface_llm_image_uri("huggingface",version="0.9.3"),

env=hub,

role=role,

)

# deploy model to SageMaker Inference

predictor = huggingface_model.deploy(

initial_instance_count=1,

instance_type="ml.g5.2xlarge",

container_startup_health_check_timeout=300,

)

# send request

predictor.predict({

"inputs": "My name is Clara and I am",

})
```

I'm getting the following errors and warning:

> **UnexpectedStatusException: Error hosting endpoint huggingface-pytorch-tgi-inference-2023-09-10-11-59-20-948: Failed. Reason: The primary container for production variant AllTraffic did not pass the ping health check. Please check CloudWatch logs for this endpoint..**

> ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
> distributed 2022.7.0 requires tornado<6.2,>=6.0.3, but you have tornado 6.3.2 which is incompatible.

> WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv

I checked the CloudWatch logs following the instructions in first error, and I found many DownloadError logs for different files. For example:

> Error: DownloadError File "/opt/conda/bin/text-generation-server", line 8, in  sys.exit(app()) File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/text_generation_server/cli.py", line 182, in download_weights utils.convert_files(local_pt_files, local_st_files, discard_names) File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/text_generation_server/utils/convert.py", line 106, in convert_files convert_file(pt_file, sf_file, discard_names) File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/text_generation_server/utils/convert.py", line 65, in convert_file loaded = torch.load(pt_file, map_location="cpu") File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 815, in load return _legacy_load(opened_file, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args) File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 1033, in _legacy_load magic_number = pickle_module.load(f, **pickle_load_args)

> 2023-09-12T02:08:45.377+08:00 _pickle.UnpicklingError: could not find MARK

Answer (score 1):

How big is your model? what I would do is launch normal sagemaker notebook and load the model there using the transformers library, then check the GPU memory footprint.

try this in the terminal: nvidia-smi

in the notebook:

```
from pynvml import *

def print_gpu_utilization():
    nvmlInit()
    handle = nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex(0)
    info = nvmlDeviceGetMemoryInfo(handle)
    print(f"GPU memory occupied: {info.used//1024**2} MB.")


def print_summary(result):
    print(f"Time: {result.metrics['train_runtime']:.2f}")
    print(f"Samples/second: {result.metrics['train_samples_per_second']:.2f}")
    print_gpu_utilization()
```

Comment: You can see the different version sizes here:
https://huggingface.co/TheBloke/Luna-AI-Llama2-Uncensored-GGML/tree/main

Are you suspecting the model is too big for the notebook? If so, what makes you think so? Otherwise, where are you going with this?

Comment: it may be the model is too big and needs more memory, the error says: "The primary container for production variant AllTraffic did not pass the ping health check"

when you deploy a model on sagemaker, sagemaker will create two endpoints, one of which is to check if the model exists in the right location and you can load it. So what you can do is to check that you are using the right instance, and if the instance is not the problem, it means the model is being downloaded in the wrong location in the container, or the model is being downloaded in the wrong format

Comment: you can try to download the model locally, upload it to s3, then deploy it from there.

You can follow this: https://www.philschmid.de/sagemaker-llm-vpc

Make sure you save the model correctly (safetensors)